# (font.html) como referencia en mi css

Tags: css

estoy actualizando una pagina web y me encuentro con:

```
src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.html)
```

cuando busco el paquete glyphicons no encuentro ese **archivo *.html** 
no entiendo esa referencia html, la borro y aparentemente no pasa nada.

mi pregunta es alguien sabe para que sirve esa referencia **src:url(regular.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, tu pregunta es interesante pues desde mi punto de vista parece algún error. Estoy tomando como punto de partida que quizá estés usando Bootstrap 3.x, si entras a la página y observas sobre el archivo [CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css) en la línea 257 en adelante, notarás que la llamada es como la siguiente:

[image: bootstrap.css]

Ahora, tampoco [documentación la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/src) menciona algo parecido.

**En resumen:** parece no tener utilidad alguna.